# knockout if and text binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I'm trying to create a simple component in Knockout (3.3.0):

```
ko.components.register('test', {
    viewModel: function() {
        this.test = 'hello'
    },
    template:
        `<span data-bind='if: 1, text: test'></span>`
});
ko.applyBindings();
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobiasfeil/mt23x9qg/).

Now when I instantiate a `<test></test>` somewhere else, I get an error:

```
Multiple bindings (if and text) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.
```

Is this really not possible? This would be like the most basic functionality to incorporate if you ask me. I know I could use `<!-- ko text -->` but what about setting other attributes like `src` and using `if` at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

OK I found the (or at least, one possible) solution: Use `<!-- ko if --><!-- /ko -->`. This way, the template can be written like

```
<!-- ko if: 1-->
<span data-bind='text: test'></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I still don't think it's perfect, in Vue I would just do `<span v-if='1'>{{text}}</span>` bam done, but I guess not everything in this world can be as awesome as Vue...

Comment: You can use ternary operator in text binding. `<span data-bind="text: 1 ? test : '' "></span>`

Comment: Oh that's true, thank you. I was overcomplicating it.